# Remove every space EXCEPT leading spaces

Tags: java, string, trim

I need to remove every spaces from a String EXCEPT leading spaces.

I have some strings that look like this :

```
"              h        ello"
```

And I am trying to achieve this :

```
"              hello"
```

That's like a reverse `trim()`.

What's the most efficient way to go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replaceAll with this regex [`(?<=\S)(\s+)(?=\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/d4smqY/1) like this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)(\\s+)(?=\\S)", "");
```

Examples of input & outputs:

```
"              h   ello  "        => "              hello  "
"              hello,  word  "    => "              hello,word  "
```

---

The first regex keep only leading and trailing spaces, if you want to keep only the leading spaces, then you can use this regex `(?<=\S)(\s+)`.

Examples of input & outputs:

```
"              hello  "         => "              hello"
"              hello,  word  "  => "              hello,word"
```

Comment: `(?=\\S)` prevents removing *trailing* spaces, but it is only *leading* spaces that should be retained.

Comment: @Andreas this is correct, I add another solution :)

Comment: *"The first regex will **remove** ..."* Did you mean "keep"?